# Vue.js 2- sweet alert package simplert not working

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vuejs2, sweetalert2

I would like to use this [library](https://mazipan.github.io/vue2-simplert/) for alerts in my app built with Laravel 5.2 version. I have installed it and created a component like this:

```
<script>
import Simplert from 'vue2-simplert'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      obj: {
        title: 'Alert Title',
        message: 'Alert Message',
        type: 'info',
        useConfirmBtn: true,
        customConfirmBtnText: 'OK'
      },
    }
  },
  methods: {
    openSimplert () {
      this.$refs.simplert.openSimplert(this.obj)
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

I am registering the component in my `app.js` like this:

```
Vue.component('alert', require('./components/Alert.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

And then trying to use it in my template:

```
<alert :useRadius="true"
       :useIcon="true"
       ref="simplert">
</alert>
```

It is part of this template:

```
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <a class="btn btn-info link-button" href="/extras/create" role="button">Lag ny extra</a>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Extras</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    @foreach($data as $extra)
                      <div class="media row">
                        <div class="media-left col-sm-3">
                          <a href="#">
                            <img class="media-object" src="/img/extras/{{ $extra->image_path }}" alt="{{ $extra->title }}">
                          </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="media-body col-sm-6">
                          <h4 class="media-heading">{{ $extra->title }}</h4>
                          <p>{{ $extra->description }}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3 action-buttons">
                          <a class="btn btn-info" href="/extras/create" role="button">Rediger</a>
                          <alert :useRadius="true"
                                 :useIcon="true"
                                 ref="simplert">
                         </alert>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Which gets included in the app template like this:

```
<div id="app">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
     ...
    </nav>

    @yield('content')
</div>
```

I can see the component in the vue debug tools, but no html is being created, I can only see this:

```
<!--function (a, b, c, d) { return createElement(vm, a, b, c, d, true); }-->
```

Ant I get the error in the console:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not
>   defined.
>
> found in
>
> --->

**Update**

After creating the new project with Laravel 5.5 since I thought the setup in Laravel 5.2 was creating problems, I have added the same library and the component and still this component throws an error, fortunately other components now work, but this still gives the same error, with the default Laravel 5.5 setup.

Comment: Could you update your question with the info where your first and your third code blocks are located? Or perhaps post their whole files?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: I'm guessing that it's because `<template></template>` is missing from `Alert.vue`

Comment: But, like I mentioned after doing changes in the package.json and gulpfile not even the components that have templates are not working

Comment: The way the simplert component is used does not seem right. Try to remove `Alert.vue` and use this to set the alert component `Vue.component('alert', require('vue2-simplert'));`. Use the component directly and do `this.$refs.simplert.openSimplert(obj)` where the component is called.

Comment: @JacobGoh I don't think that has anything to do with this, somehow the templates on all components are not compiled

Comment: You need to define a `<template>` section in your `Alert` component

Comment: When I do that, I don't have error any more, but also I have an empty template, I am obviously implementing the package in a wrong way, but not sure how to do it correctly?

Comment: "How to implement the vue2-simplert package" is a different (and very broad) question. Please [read their documentation](https://github.com/mazipan/vue2-simplert/wiki/Usage-Guidance) and refine your post to make it clear what you've tried and what isn't working as expected.

Comment: Well, I have posted in the question already all the steps of the package implementation, I have really no idea what I can add to make it even more clearly.

Comment: "When I do that, I don't have error any more, but also I have an empty template" It's hard to know what exactly that means because you haven't updated your post to show what you're trying.

Comment: By that I meant I have just added empty template tag like this ```<template></template>``` to the component, but since that is not described in the documentation I have left it out of the question, since it was just a suggestion here in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out that [simplert also exists as Vue plugin](https://github.com/mazipan/vue2-simplert-plugin). That should simplify the complete process and it is much better implemented as it uses an event bus for opening/closing and it doesn't use any longer `$refs` which should be avoided according to the [official Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs).

You would do then for example in your **app.js**:

```
import Simplert from 'vue2-simplert-plugin'
Vue.use(Simplert)

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    obj: {
      title: 'Alert Title',
      message: 'Alert Message',
      type: 'info',
      useConfirmBtn: true,
      customConfirmBtnText: 'OK'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    openSimplert () {
      this.$Simplert.open(this.obj)
    },
    closeSimplert () {
      this.$Simplert.close()
    }
  }
})
```

In your **Larvavel template** just use:

```
@section('content')
  // ...
    <simplert></simplert>
  // ...
@endsection
```

The simplert docs in the wiki are a bit confusing and not up-to-date regarding the plugin. Let me know if that works for you!

Comment: When I use the above I get the warning `[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <simplert> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.`

Comment: Perhaps you didn’t install correctly? Do you import and then do Vue.use(Simplert) ?

Comment: Yes but it's likley I've done something wrong as this is first time using Vue. I have created a question here with file contents: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54440029/error-when-using-vue-plugin-in-laravel-unknown-custom-element-simplert