# Error when using Vue plugin in Laravel: Unknown custom element: <simplert>

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to use the [Simplert Vue plugin](https://github.com/mazipan/vue2-simplert-plugin) within my Laravel 5.7 app but I'm getting the following error:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the
>   component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide
>   the "name" option.

I have based my code on answer from this question [Vue.js 2- sweet alert package simplert not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48164368/vue-js-2-sweet-alert-package-simplert-not-working/48174079)

app.js file:

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');

import Simplert from 'vue2-simplert-plugin'
require('vue2-simplert-plugin/dist/vue2-simplert-plugin.css')
Vue.use(Simplert)

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    obj: {
      title: 'Alert Title',
      message: 'Alert Message',
      type: 'info',
      useConfirmBtn: true,
      customConfirmBtnText: 'OK'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    openSimplert () {
      this.$Simplert.open(this.obj)
    },
    closeSimplert () {
      this.$Simplert.close()
    }
  }
})
```

home.blade.php template:

```
@section('content')
  // ..
  <simplert></simplert>
  // ..
```

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "vue2-simplert-plugin": "^0.5.3"
}
```

In VSCode, there is a hint on the following line `import Simplert from 'vue2-simplert-plugin'` in my app.js file:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue2-simplert-plugin'.
>   'x/node_modules/vue2-simplert-plugin/dist/vue2-simplert-plugin.js'
>   implicitly has an 'any' type.

Could this be the problem?

Comment: Have you resolved the issue? I have the exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

When registering a Vue component, you need to include a name, list below:

```
export default {
        name: 'example-name',
        data() {
            return {
            }
        },
```

so in your case:

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  name: 'example-name'
  data: {
    obj: {
      title: 'Alert Title',
      message: 'Alert Message',
      type: 'info',
      useConfirmBtn: true,
      customConfirmBtnText: 'OK'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    openSimplert () {
      this.$Simplert.open(this.obj)
    },
    closeSimplert () {
      this.$Simplert.close()
    }
  }
})
```

**ALTERNATIVELY**

you should create a file in your resources->js->components folder called something like `ExampleComponent.vue`. Within here you place all of your template code (what the '#app' div should display).

**with that file you should include:**

```
<template>
    //code here...
</tempate>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'example-component-name',
        data() {
            return {
                obj: {
                    title: 'Alert Title',
                    message: 'Alert Message',
                    type: 'info',
                    useConfirmBtn: true,
                    customConfirmBtnText: 'OK'
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            //methods here
        } 
    }
</script>
```

**and then within your app.js file all you need to do is:**

```
require('./bootstrap');

import Simplert from 'vue2-simplert-plugin'
require('vue2-simplert-plugin/dist/vue2-simplert-plugin.css')
Vue.use(Simplert)

Vue.component('example-component-name',require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
```

This should help in your situation - let me know :)

Comment: if this doensn't work for you I have an alternative solution

Comment: Thanks, I've tried both of those. Adding name just gives me same error. I struggled when Creating a component - keep getting error `Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI` after `running npm run watch`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but i faced the same issu and once the plugin is registered in App.vue, some components works fine with:

```
<Simplert></Simplert>
```

and some with

```
<simplert></simplert>
```

The only diff is the Uppercase / Lowercase but some components accepts the Uppercase when other not and i must use Lowercase.